# Python decorator for permission

Tags: python, django, decorator

it is my first time to use a decorator and I want to show something like this

```
import functools

def checkUser(tag):
    def dec(f0):
        @functools.wraps(f0)
        def wrapper(userName, loggedinUser):

            if userName == loggedinUser:
                 return "You are allowed to view this page"
            else:
                 return "Error"
        return wrapper
    return dec

@checkUser
def test2(userName, loggedinUser):
    return userName, loggedinUser

print test2()
```

and I am pretty sure it wouldn't work, this is just my idea. I just copied this codes and edited. I am really new to this.

Comment: Well, have you tried it? Maybe it does work. No way of knowing without trying...

Answer (score 2):

For the code you given, if you just want to check the user, there is no need for you to use the decorator, why not just compare them directly? Since you want to use decorator the check for permission. I think you may want to do this way:

```
import functools

def check_user(username, password):
    def dec(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapper(login_user, login_password):
            f(login_user, login_password)
            if username == login_user and password == login_password:
                 return "You are allowed to view this page"
            else:
                 return "Check your password and username"
        return wrapper
    return dec


@check_user('jhon', 'passwd')
def test2(login_user, login_password):
    print "hello, {0}".format(login_user)


print test2('jhon', 'foobar')
print test2('jhon', 'passwd')
```

and the output should be:

```
hello, jhon
Check your password and username
hello, jhon
You are allowed to view this page
```

you can see that on the first time, input the wrong password will give us the warning, but when we input the right info, it is showing us the success message.